# Javascript: Is there a limit to "else if" statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am getting value from a text field. I have one if and several else if statement.

The problem the last else if doesn't execute even if the condition is true.

If I change the last else if to if it executes and gives alert. When I change that back to else if the statement doesn't execute. The else if before that is fine as it's firing/executing on a particular condition.

```
function Valcheck()
{

var txtVal = document.getElementById("sometextField").value;



if(txtVal =="%") 
    {

        alert("% is only allowed with other characters.");
        return;
    }       

    else if(txtVal.indexOf("%") != -1) 
    {
        if((txtVal.indexOf('%')) != (txtVal.length-1)) 
        {
            alert(" % is only allowed at the end.");
            return;
        }       
    } 
    else if(txtVal.indexOf(",") != -1) 
    {
        alert("Comma or comma separated values are not allowed.");
        return;

    } 
    else if(( txtVal.length  >0) &&  (txtVal.indexOf("%") == -1)) 
    {
        alert("Please enter % at the end of the value.");
        return;
    }            

    else if( txtVal.length > 11 ) 
    {

        alert(" Value can't be greater than 11 characters.");
        return;

    }

}
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if `txtVal.length > 11`, then either this is met:

```
    else if(txtVal.indexOf("%") != -1)
```

or this is met:

```
    else if(( txtVal.length  >0) &&  (txtVal.indexOf("%") == -1))
```

So that it will never reach the `else if( txtVal.length > 11 )`. You need to change this:

```
    else if(txtVal.indexOf("%") != -1) 
    {
        if((txtVal.indexOf('%')) != (txtVal.length-1)) 
        {
            alert(" % is only allowed at the end.");
            return;
        }       
    }
```

to this:

```
    else if(txtVal.indexOf("%") != -1 && txtVal.indexOf('%') != (txtVal.length-1))
    {
        alert(" % is only allowed at the end.");
        return;
    }
```

so that it doesn't "capture" the case where `txtVal.indexOf('%') == (txtVal.length-1)`.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a limit to the number of `if` statements. The issue is that one of the previous `if` statements catches the case you're testing.

Go through each `if` statements for the case your testing and see if it's beging caught by a previous one.

Comment: thanks you can see that the previous one doesn't catch the condition i am trying to test. You can look at the last else if statement.

Comment: Nomad -- you are wrong the previous txtVal.length>0 DOES catch the condition -- the second part of that previous if is superflous as you can't "get past" the previous test to ensure there's a "%" in the field

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your `else if(txtVal.indexOf("%") != -1)` is true (so, second if from the top), but condition for "if" inside it is not true (so it doesn't go to "return".

Answer (score 1):

there is no way that the last 'else-if' be hit:
if the textVal has a '%' in it it will go to the second 'else-if'
and if it does not have '%' it will go to the one before the last one.
so the last if never be hit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to if else nesting.  There is a logical barrier to getting to nested if else clauses.  Look into using

```
switch(caseVariable){
  case 1:  document.write("caseVariable = " + 1);
           break;
  case 35:  document.write("caseVariable = " + 35);
           break;
  default: break;
}
```

Comment: I guess I can't apply switch statement in my condition.