# Is there a limit to “else if” statements?

Tags: optimization, coding-style, refactoring

I would like to ask there a limit on how many "else if" clause we can put? I have been told that if we are having too many "else if", it will lead to stack overflow eventually. For example:

```
    if (1 > 1){}
    else if (1 > 2){}
    else if (1 > 3 ){}
      //and so on
    else{}
```

However, I can't find any evidence on this subject, and Googling doesn't give me the answer that I want. The question below is has the same title, but has nothing related to the subject that I wanted to ask. Thanks in advanced.

[Javascript: Is there a limit to "else if" statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812814/javascript-is-there-a-limit-to-else-if-statements)

Comment: what language are you asking about?

Comment: there is no specific language, but let us treat it as C.

Comment: My answer holds for C and any language you're likely to encounter, then.

Comment: Experimentally, when I try to exec a statement with 8941 `elif` clauses, it works, but with one more I get a `RecursionError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any reasonable language the limit should be the same as the limit for code size in general, in other words so big you'll practically never reach it.

It definitely won't lead to a stack overflow, however, because an `if` doesn't add to the stack. A function call adds another frame to the stack, an `if` is a branch instruction.

Comment: So if I understand if correctly, the real culprit is nested function calls, but not the large amount of "else if"?

Comment: Culprit for a stack overflow? Yes, it's almost always unbounded recursion.

Comment: a large amount of `else if` won't overflow the stack or cause a crash, but if you have pages and pages of it then it's a sign that the code should be structured better. Just because you can doesn't mean you *should*..